# Why does findall not return the whole match when matching with a group?

Tags: python, regex

As I have read `(dog|cat)food` will look for `dog food` and `cat food` but I am unable to reproduce it with my case.

```
>>> for m in re.findall('RA[a-zA-Z0-9]*',"RAJA45909"):
    print(m)


RAJA45909
>>> for m in re.findall('(ra|RA)[a-zA-Z0-9]*',"RAJA45909"):
    print(m)


RA
>>>
```

Could somebody help me to understand this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.finditer) instead of [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.findall) and then print the whole matching group:

```
>>> for m in re.finditer('(ra|RA)[a-zA-Z0-9]*',"RAJA45909"):
...     print(m.group())
... 
RAJA45909
```

The documentation of `findall` says:

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of
>   groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one
>   group.

Your regex has only one group and thus the result is a list of texts matched by that single group. If we add an other group you see:

```
>>> for m in re.findall('(ra|RA)([a-zA-Z0-9]*)',"RAJA45909"):
...     print(m)
... 
('RA', 'JA45909')
```

So `findall` when used with groups matches the whole regex but only returns the portions matched by the groups. While `finditer` always returns a complete match object.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this

```
print(re.findall('((?:ra|RA)[a-zA-Z0-9]*)',"RAJA45909"))
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/N4ZdQL)**